# dynamically calculate the sum of fields time data 24 hours format

Tags: php, ajax

I have two fields, field1 10:30 field2 10:45  field 3 total: 15:00 mins.

I want to calculate the fields and display it on a third and found something that may work.

Here is my code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript"><!--
  function updatesum() {
 document.form.sum.value = (document.form.sum1.value -0) + 
   (document.form.sum2.value -0);
     }
     //--></script>


    <form name="form" >
   Enter a number:
  <input name="sum1" onChange="updatesum()" />
     and another number:
 <input name="sum2" onChange="updatesum()" />
   Their sum is:
  <input name="sum" readonly style="border:0px;">
    </form>
```

Comment: Why is this php if there's no php? It's not even ajax, it's javascript

Answer (score 0):

Use

`resultSum = document.getElementsByName('sum1')[0] + document.getElementsByName('sum2')[0];`

to calculate the sum. Then use `document.getElementsByName('sum')[0].value = resultSum` and it will print that value into your last input field.